# &= yields false on even numbers

Tags: php, operators, boolean, variable-assignment

I've stumbled upon something odd, and I can't find any answers anywhere. &= seems to interpret even numbers as false. Is there a logical explanation for this, or is this a bug?

This snippet reproduces the problem, at least on my setup:

```
$nums = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$var1 = true;
$var2 = true;
foreach ($nums as $num) {
    // Test
    $var1 &= $num;
    $var2 = $var2 && $num;
    echo "$var1, $var2<br />";
    //Reset
    $var1 = true;
    $var2 = true;
}
```

System: PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are confusing [**Bitwise AND (`&`)**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) with [**Logical AND (`&&`)**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). No, they are not the same.

Bitwise operations are best understood if you inspect the binary representation of numbers. Here is what happens with even/odd numbers:

```
/* 1 & 0 */ 00000001b & 00000000b // 00000000b
/* 1 & 1 */ 00000001b & 00000001b // 00000001b
/* 1 & 2 */ 00000001b & 00000010b // 00000000b
/* 1 & 3 */ 00000001b & 00000011b // 00000001b
```

For logical operations, you simply need to look at the *truthiness* of operands:

```
1 && 0 // false -- 0 is falsy
1 && 1 // true  -- any non-zero number is truthy
1 && 2 // true
1 && 3 // true
```

Comment: That makes sense. I know the difference between bitwise and logical operators, I was just taught that that &= was shorthand for x = x && y... I have to go kick somebody... hard... I've been using this for years. I feel so stupid. I noticed =& behaves differently, what is its function?

Comment: `=&` is `= &` I believe... `$a = &$b` means `$a` is assigned a reference to `$b`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a bitwise AND on the numbers.

The numbers in binary are...

```
1  => 0001
2  => 0010
3  => 0011
4  => 0100
5  => 0101
6  => 0110
7  => 0111
8  => 1000
9  => 1001
10 => 1010
```

Realise that when you increment the number, the least significant digit is always changing, and since you're ANDing with `1`, it will look like the even numbers are false as the result is `0` (`0000 & 1` is `0`).